# Replace non-numeric characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to replace non-numeric chars from a string.

For example, "8-4545-225-144" needs to be "84545225144"; "$334fdf890==-" must be "334890".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
''.join(c for c in S if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: I hate it when people slam a list comprehension when a generator expression is the right option. You, sir, win one internet (and an upvote).

Comment: +1 for non-regex solution.
i hate when peoples use regex for everything,
some goals is better suited with non-regex solution

Comment: @killown: I personally find the regex option more readable. Maybe it's because I've done so much work with regexes, but looking at @KennyTM's code I can immediately see what it does; this one takes me a second to understand.

Answer (score 18):

It is possible with regex.

```
import re

...

return re.sub(r'\D', '', theString)
```

Answer (score 3):

`filter(str.isdigit, s)` is faster and IMO clearer than anything else listed here.

It will also throw a TypeError if s is a unicode type. Depending on what definition of "digits" you want, this can be more or less useful than the alternative `filter(type(s).isdigit, s)`, slightly slower but still faster than the re and comprehension versions for me.

**Edit:** Although if you are a poor sucker stuck with Python 3, you will need to use `"".join(filter(str.isdigit, s))` which puts you firmly in the realm of equivalently bad performance. Such progress.

Answer (score 1):

Let's time the `join` and the `re` versions:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: def withRe(theString): return re.sub('\D', '', theString)
   ...:

In [5]:

In [6]: def withJoin(S): return ''.join(c for c in S if c.isdigit())
   ...:


In [11]: s = "8-4545-225-144"

In [12]: %timeit withJoin(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.89 us per loop

In [13]: %timeit withRe(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.77 us per loop
```

The `join` version is much nicer, compared to the `re` one, but unfortunately is 50% slower. So if the performance is an issue, the elegance might need to be sacrificed.

**EDIT**

```
In [16]: def withFilter(s): return filter(str.isdigit, s)
   ....:
In [19]: %timeit withFilter(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.75 us per loop
```

It looks like `filter` is the performance and readability winner

Answer (score 0):

Although a little more complicated to set up, using the `translate()` string method to delete the characters as shown below can as much as 4-6 times faster than using `join()` or `re.sub()` according to timing tests I performed -- so if it is something done many times, you might want to consider using this instead.

```
nonnumerics = ''.join(c for c in ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256)) if not c.isdigit())

astring = '123-$ab #6789'
print astring.translate(None, nonnumerics)
# 1236789
```

Comment: The str.translate method is preferred over string.translate.

Comment: @Roger Pate, good point, old habits are hard to break... I've updated the code in my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out and allowing me to improve the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer regular expressions, so here's a way if you like

```
import re
myStr = '$334fdf890==-'
digts = re.sub('[^0-9]','',myStr)
```

This should replace all nonnumeric occurences with '' i.e. with nothing. So digts variable should be '334890'